# JSF logout using session.invalidate does not clear the current username?

Tags: jsf, httpsession

In my JSF application, I get the name of the currently signed in user like this ...

```
public String getLoggedInUsername() {
  return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();
}
```

... and I check if the user is signed in like this ...

```
public boolean isSignedIn() {
  return (getLoggedInUsername() != null);
}
```

... and when the user signs out, I do this ...

```
public String doLogout() {
  FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession)facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
  httpSession.invalidate();
  return "main";
}
```

My problem is after doLogout(), the getLoggedInUsername() still returns the name of the user that was logged in.  What am I supposed to do to make sure getRemoteUser() returns null after logout?

Alternately, is there a better way to get if isSignedIn() than just checking the username?

Thanks!
Rob

Comment: Did you debug the involved methods itself, or did you guess/conclude it yourself based on how the webbrowser behaves? The page might be plain requested from the browser cache...

Comment: Yes, I debugged it.  I hit the doLogout() method, after it's complete, I hit the getLoggedInUsername() and it returns the username of the guy who was logged in (even after the session.invalidate was run).  Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know if I'm sending a redirect. :)  I guess I'm using whatever the default behavior is, on doLogOut() the browser leaves whatever page I was on and shows the main.jsf page (which you don't have to be signed in to see, by the way).  Does that help?

Comment: Yes, I already guessed that. I deleted the comment and moved it to an answer before you commented. It's a redirect when the URL in browser address bar changes to the target URL instead of sticking to the URL where the form is submitted to.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ensure that you're redirecting the request after invalidating the session. The user principal is resolved based on a session attribute. So when you just forward to the target page (as a JSF navigation case by default does), then it'll still be there in the target page since it uses the *same* `HttpSession` reference. A redirect instructs the webbrowser to fire a brand new HTTP request, hereby forcing the server to recreate the `HttpSession` reference based on the new request.

Add `<redirect/>` to the navigation case to force JSF to send a redirect. Or when you're already in JSF 2.0, add `?faces-redirect=true` to the outcome value.

Answer (score 0):

After call "session.invalidate();" , add "request.logout();".

Method invalidate on session object just clean session data.

Method logout on request object establish null as the value returned when getUserPrincipal, getRemoteUser, and getAuthType is called on the request.