# How to validate/invalidate sessions jsp/servlets?

Tags: jsp, session, servlets, invalidation

I opened the session in my servlet when the user performed a successful login:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("name", name);
```

then I wrote in the logout.jsp to terminate the session:

```
<%session.invalidate();%>
```

To check if a session is valid I am doing this:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String name = (String) session.getAttribute("name");
```

But it is not working, I am getting the session valid even after the session.invalidate.
Does anyone understand where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like already answered:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899500/jsf-logout-using-session-invalidate-does-not-clear-the-current-username

Comment: no it does not answer to my problem, I am talking jsp/servlets and not jsf tags. at the other hand I want to know what problem do I have in my code

Comment: The idea is the same, you should redirect the request to a new page, than the container will finally invalidate your old session.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you should call session.getSession(false) - which returns null if there is no current session.

according to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29)

> `HttpSession#getSession(boolean create)` - create - true to create a new session for this request if necessary; false to return null if there's no current session.

So the correct way of session value check would -

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if(session!=null)
  session.setAttribute("name", name);
```

and once you invalidate the session -

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if(session!=null)
session.invalidate();
```

Comment: thank you, so request.getSession(false) if the session is active, what will return? Excuse me but I want to really understand this.

Comment: it will return your current session.

Comment: This is the right answer. Just to add @AlbanoVito you might be interested in [clearing the browser cache](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3902700/1317692) aswell.

Answer (score -1):

To Validate the Session

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("name", name);
```

To invalidate it you need to do

```
session.removeAttribute("name");
session.invalidate();
```

But you need to keep one thing in mind that the object may became invalid but this doesnot mean that it will cleaned immediately, even after invalidating it after all its attributes gone it is possible that sesssion object will get reused, I got the same user ID and creation time.