# How to disable html controls after a user logins in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, hidden

Here's the situation..
 1. I got a home page with options of **Login | Register | Contact | About me** in jsp..
 2. Its basically a online shopping website..
 3. When the user visits the website.. the **Login | Register |** should be visible, but when a user logs in with his user id and pass his Username and logout button should replace the Login and Register links..

for example.. 
Common Home Page : **Login | Register | Contact | About me**

Logged in Home Page : **Welcome abcde | Logout | Contact | About me**

i am not getting the logic of it... if sme 1 can demonstrate me it will be of great help.

Comment: if you using normal html link for the options as shown in the question, then use if else using scriptlet or with jstl <c:if>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in following way..

```
 <body>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="/home.jsp">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/aboutus.jsp">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contactus.jsp">Contact</a></li>
            <%
                String username= (String) session.getAttribute("user");                     
                if (username == null) {
            %>
            <li><a href="/register.jsp">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="/login.jsp">Login</a></li>

        <% } else {
         %>
            <li>Hi, <%=username %>  (<a href="/logout.jsp">Logout</a>)</li>
        <% }%>
        </ul>
    </body>
```

and in your servlet put this code

```
  HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
  String user = request.getParameter("username");
  session.setAttribute("user", name);
```

Comment: also dude if i click logout, the same common home page should be displayed.. for that...?

Comment: same common page will be displayed except it will have login and register link on navigation bar..

Comment: yah...? coz if i give the link of homepage.jsp.. it will give me a page with the "Welcome abcde | Logout | Contact | About me" and i want it to be like this "Login | Register | Contact | About me" after LOGOUT button is clicked

Comment: you need to check whether user session exists or not . i suggest make above navigationbar as header to each page and whithin each page add header i.e <%@include file="header.jsp" %>

Comment: u mean to say i gotcha request.getSession(false)?

Comment: yes logout user when he will click on logout link session.invalidate(); see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445024/how-to-validate-invalidate-sessions-jsp-servlets

Comment: thanks for ur help really appreciate... :) for that header idea.... i know it might be easy for u bt... it took a lot of time from me earlier coz i was copy pasting the code to every jsp page.. it would be a lot useful ahead..

Comment: Use **username.equals("null")** to compare strings.