# How can I hide/disable Sign up and login button after user logs in, on every page?

Tags: html, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I want to hide Signup and Login buttons on every page after user logs in and show only logout, and after logging out there should be those previous buttons signup and login. I'm using Eclipse

[How to disable html controls after a user logins in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557874/how-to-disable-html-controls-after-a-user-logins-in-jsp) is the best one I've found but it's not working. Why?

```
    <ul><li><h1 style="font-size:40px">Car Care</h1></li></ul></a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Home.jsp">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Aboutus.jsp">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="Services.jsp">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="Branches.jsp">Locations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Promotions</a></li>
    <li><a href="Getintouch.jsp">Get in Touch</a></li>   
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation-bar1">
  <div id="navigation-container1">
  <ul>
 
    <li><a href="Signup.jsp">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="Signin.jsp">Already A Member? Sign In</a></li>
  
   </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  <header>
  <div class="main">
  <div class="backp1">
  <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/img/<%="login.png" %>" 
   name="uimage" id="uimage"/>
   </div>
<div id="tableContainer-1">
<div id="tableContainer-2">

     <form  name="signin" method="post" action="LoginServlet">
            
            <table id="myTable">
            
            <hr>
            <caption><h3>Login</h3></caption>   
            <p text align="center">Sign In With Your Details</p>            
            
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td><input type="text"  placeholder="Username" name="Uname" 
              id="suname"  required/></td>
                
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" placeholder="Password 
                "name="Password" id="spassword" required/></td>
                
            </tr>

            
            <tr>
                
                <td><button type="reset" class="resetbtn" 
         value="reset">Reset</button>
                <td><button type="submit" class="signinbtn" value="Sign Up" 
              name="submit" id="submit">Login</button></td>
                
            </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>

            </tr>
        </table>
```

This is my list and sign in.

Answer (score 0):

After the user has signed in you can store this in a session scope variable

```
session.setAttribute("Username", Username);
```

On every page just check if this attribute exists

```
String Username = session.getAttribute("Username");
if (Username==null) { // show the signin and register buttons
```

Comment: It's still not working , oh and I'm already using sessions in the servlet with these two codes "String username = request.getParameter("Uname"); 
            session.setAttribute("sessname",username); "  maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Strange! Sure that Its not a typo (username instead of Username)? Its like the session is invalidated quickly or so.. Have you tried System.out.println(session.getAttribute("Username"));  here and there to see if the session is saved. May be Session Persistence is disabled? What container are you using?

Comment: okay I figured it out. I had to do some little changes. Both codes were right(the link in my post). session was already in my servlet and all I had to do was
`<%String Username = (String) session.getAttribute("sessname");` cuz in my login servlet I've used `session.setAttribute( "sessname" ,username);`
That's All :)

Comment: Naming a variable sessname instead of what it actual is is asking for problems and delays like this... That's why I said to check for typos what probably let you to checking the name.. :D

Comment: Yeah Thank You!. I know it's been 11 months. but if you could update the answer with including the existing Answer , I could mark it. :D.