# Orbeon security doesn't work correctly for orbeon embedded api

Tags: jsp, session, https, session-cookies, orbeon

I set up `j_security_check` with form authentication on my orbeon app and it works fine. Orbeon is under URL https://localhost:8444/orbeon/.

The problem is that I have embedded orbeon API in my jsp page which is under URL
https://localhost:8444/BackOffice/form.jsp. On this page I display some orbeon form and when I try to go to this jsp page login page pop up instead.

I changed the cookie path to `/` (instead of `/orbeon`) in web.xml:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <path>/</path>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

but it didn't help. I'm still facing the same problem.

When I look at the HTTP requests I can see that when I'm trying to reach the JSP page, an HTTP request with 2 JSESSIONIDs is issued (one for orbeon, one for backoffice), so everything should works fine but it doesn't.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I attempted a response below, but I may have misunderstood your question, and you'll let me know if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

By embedding, I assume that you're referring to the [Form Runner Java Embedding API](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/link-embed/java-api.html). If that is the case, end-users should never be hitting `/orbeon` directly, assuming is this where Orbeon Forms is deployed. Instead they should go through your app, which includes the form produced by Orbeon Forms.

Comment: Orbeon is deployed under url /orbeon and my app is under url /backoffice. Form is embedded in my jsp page which is under url /backoffice/form.jsp   On both apps (orbeon and backoffice) I have j_security_check form basic authentication. After I log in to orbeon and backoffice when I go to my jsp page, orbeon login page pop up instead

Comment: @piechos Let's see; I'm afraid I might be missing something here. You shouldn't need to log into `/orbeon` at all, just into `/backoffice`. And users should only be accessing `/backoffice`. If you have permissions setup in your forms, defined in Form Builder for the forms, Orbeon Forms needs to know who the user is. This information is known the Orbeon code you're call from your app, and that code passes that information along to Orbeon Forms. Does this make sense?