# JSP page still logged after logout

Tags: java, jsp

I have a problem in my project about JSP page.

When user logout, it redirected to the login page (until here its ok).

But, if user uses the browser "back" button, he can browse the "user_page" again. So, its like still "logged in".

I need a help to solve this. I already tried a lot of things since start looking for fix this.

Ps.: I noticed too that if user uses the browser "refresh" in "user_page" when back in it after logged out, the browser redirect it to login page normally and user will not able to back again.

This is the **Logout.java** code:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Logout", urlPatterns = {"/logout"})
public class Logout extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

       request.getSession().invalidate();
       response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/");

    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit with your code and this will make easy to read and help you with this problem

Comment: Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/prevent-user-from-seeing-previously-visited-secured-page-after-logout

Comment: You didn't explain what the *logout* do exactly: load a new page, redirect to another page, or just change the current page..

Comment: @MarioSantini The "logout" redirect user to the "login.jsp" page.

Comment: @esprittn about this post, about filter, I don't understand how to communicate this filter sample. Did you have a "generic" sample idea?

Comment: @SayuriMizuguchi Ok. Edited now with code.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445024/how-to-validate-invalidate-sessions-jsp-servlets

Comment: @RC. your solution works for me, but just in Chrome. In Firefox still not working. Tested in more machines.