# Invalidating previous session at Login: JSF 2

Tags: session, jsf-2, web.xml, welcome-file

I have a filter to be called which finds, after every page is requested if the user & session is privileged and valid respectively. But I want to invalidate the session at beginning, just before the login. Because if someone does not log out it is capturing that session if active, while next login. There is an index.jsp which is redirecting to the page after doing this job. but if the login page is hit directly then it captures the previous session.

> LoginManagedBean.java

```
    public LoginManagedBean() {
    super(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext());
    System.out.println(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
    System.out.println(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext());
    user = new UserBean();
}
```

> Index.jsp

```
request.getSession(false).invalidate();
String redirectPage = null;
redirectPage = request.getContextPath()+"/xhtml/login/loginHome.xhtml";
```

Another problem is although I have index.jsp as welcome-file the "loginHome.xhtml" still opens directly from hitting the context root. Thats when the session invalidation is not happening.

> web.xml

```
    <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

Thanks.. !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF logout using session.invalidate does not clear the current username?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899500/jsf-logout-using-session-invalidate-does-not-clear-the-current-username)

Comment: I got through that thread but that one was the problem with logout. I have that handled. Where as I am trying to create a new session verytime the loginpage comes. So that if the previous user hadn't logged out but just closed the window, it will invalidate that old session .

Comment: What happens if you invalidate the session in preRenderView of your loginHome.xhtml page?